# Filter powerbi report with spaces in query string

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-teams, powerbi-desktop

I have a PowerBI report which is pulling data from Microsoft's Live source and is about call history from Microsoft Teams Tenant.

The report loads in PowerBI, however, I am trying to generate URL so that we can filter the report based on email or phone number. The end URL that I have is :

https://app.powerbi.com/groups/0070c91d-9b02-48dd-8dc4-69324e6eb6cc/reports/5c9d89c1-5954-4637-b2d9-ce6378083a71?filter=CQD/Second%20Phone%20Number eq '+17172160426'

CQD is the name of the live source.
However, since the column name have space "Second Phone Number" the filter is not working with escape characters.

Can someone suggest what should be an alternative in this scenario as I can't change the name of the field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix with an _x and use unicode then an underscore. e.g. Second Phone Number becomes

> Second_x0020_Phone_x0020_Number

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-table-and-column-names